# jQuery Colorbox background transition effect?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I find the background transition of the jQuery Colorbox very 'hard'. I couldn't find a setting where I can specify a custom transition. **Is it possible to create a fade-effect for the background like [Nyro Modal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/#demos) has?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATED 2** *<sup>with easing effects</sup>*

**DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-colorbox-background-transition-effect/

```
$('.example').colorbox({
    //added to remove initial flickering
    opacity : 0,
    //use the onOpen event...
    onOpen: function() {
        // prevent Overlay from being displayed...
        $('#cboxOverlay,#colorbox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        // make the overlay visible and
        // re-add all it's original properties!
        $('#cboxOverlay').css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'opacity': 0.9,
            'cursor': 'pointer'
            // execute our original animation on the overlay!
            // animate it you can use here all the
            // possible animate combination or plugin...
        }).animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 1000 , function() {
            $('#colorbox').css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        }).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your example looks alright, however displaying of the box does not 'wait' for the background displaying to finish... I don't think there is a valid solution for that..?

Comment: you are welcome bro! ;-) don't forget that you can of course use animate instead of fadeIn and viceversa! also use the easing plugin that rook!

Comment: Whoops, while testing in my app I noticed that the overlay shows/hides in a fraction of a second... This produces a very irritating flicker of the screen... Is there a workaround for this..?

Comment: set the `1000` to 2000 or more!

Comment: no doesn't help... before this line is executed | $('#cboxOverlay,#colorbox').css('visibility', 'hidden'); |
the #cboxOverlay div is already visible for ~0.01 seconds...

Comment: I found a solution to the last problem myself, you might want to update your answer. It includes passing {opacity:0} as a setting. Then the default overlay show() function doesn't really show, because it's 0 opacity. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Barlas: please, consider re-voting up, you can't down-vote just because the demo is not working anymore, the demo has been submitted a while ago, you always have to refer to the source above not just demo. Anyway i have updated the demo. now it is working right. thanks for the time.

Comment: @Barlas: note that the link is changed or try clearing the cache.