# transparent background for colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I would like to have transparent background for outside of colorbox modal. currently use the css style from this colorbox demo http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/ . based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760970/233933, I could do transparent backgournd with:

```
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"30%",
    onOpen: function() {
        // make the overlay visible and re-add all it's original properties!
        $('#cboxOverlay').css({
            'visibility': 'visible', 
            'opacity':0.5, 
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        });
        $('#colorbox').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' }).fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

but I would like to have the transparent style for all my colorbox modals. I tried to edit the colorbox.css file to include:

```
#cboxOverlay{ visibility: visible; opacity: 0.5 }
#colorbox{ visibility: visible }
```

but that doesn't change anything. your suggestion?

**UPDATED**

updated wording so it is clear that I want outside of the modal to be transparent.
thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
#cboxOverlay{ visibility: visible; opacity: 0.5 !important;}
```

There are inline styles applied to the overlay that currently override your opacity setting.

More detailed explanation: there's an inline style attribute being attached to the `#cboxOverlay` element that says `opacity:0.9`. This overrides your stylesheet. If you put `!important` next to your rule, it is not pushed aside in favor of the inline style.

Comment: I have no clue about your answer(which inline style, why override opacity setting?) but it works!

Comment: @perlwle Well that's not good. I've tried to explain it a little better.

Comment: I see that colorbox itselt has opacity default to 0.9. your change makes sense now.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For transparent background (inside colorbox) you should set:
`#cboxContent {
background: transparent;
}`

Comment: +1 I also had to do `#cboxLoadedContent{background: transparent;}` to make the inner background transparent. Of course it is now 6 years later.